# Why does Firefox break my CSS grid with using a horizontal scroll area?

Tags: html, css

I would like to work with this code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  padding: 10px;
}

.text {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  background-color: red;
  /* overflow: hidden; → Firefox needs that. Why? */
}

.horizontal-scroll {
  background-color: green;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.horizontal-scroll div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="text">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="horizontal-scroll">
      <div>This container is horizontally scrollable. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, if I use Firefox on macOS, the grid layout gets destroyed. It only works if I add `overflow: hidden;` to the `.text` class. But this is not a solution for me, because I need to place an object inside the text area that protrudes from it.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: try min-width:0 on .text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOT WORKING**: <del>**Remove** `white-space: nowrap;`</del>

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  padding: 10px;
}

.text {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  background-color: red;
  /* overflow: hidden; → Firefox needs that. Why? */
}

.horizontal-scroll {
  background-color: green;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.horizontal-scroll div {
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="text">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="horizontal-scroll">
      <div>This container is horizontally scrollable. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## EDIT 1:

### Use `width: -moz-available;` on `#text`

Comment: Sorry, but I need a horizontal scroll area! The "white-space: nowrap;" is absolutely needed.

Comment: so what do you want your grid to look like. Any explaination please !!

Comment: It should look exactly the way it looks like. The problem is that Firefox destroys the layout. For this a bugfix is needed. But the design shouldn't be changed in any way.

Comment: You should make a bug report on it & Remove that down vote

Comment: "width: -moz-available;" works! Thank you! <3